# Animate CSS on owl.carousel.change

Tags: javascript, html, owl-carousel

I use this owl-carousel and add animate.css for some text in this slider. Now animation work good on start, and that's it. I need some solution, how to do in js to .addClass and .removeClass on owl.carousel.change. I tried something, but didn't work.

```
 <div id="BG" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
     <div class="bg-item1">
        <div class="container row h-100">
            <div class="col-sm-12 align-self-center">
                <div class="bg-txt animated fadeInRight delay-2s">
                    <span style="text-transform: uppercase; font-weight:bold;"> SOME TEXT </span>                                          
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="bg-item2">
         <div class="container row h-100">
             <div class="col-sm-12 align-self-center">
                  <div class="bg-txt animated fadeInRight delay-2s ">
                     <span style="text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold;"> SOME TEXT </span       
                   </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Owl carousel caption with animate.css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43327384/owl-carousel-caption-with-animate-css)

Comment: Yes, that is it, but i tried this and some didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library **Owl Carousel 2** supports [animated slide transitions](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/animate.html). You can pass the animated classes you would like to add to the **`animateIn`** and **`animateOut`** properties. See the snippet below for a working example using **`animateIn`**:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var owl = $('.owl-carousel');

  owl.owlCarousel({
    animateIn: 'fadeInRight delay-2s',
    items: 1,
    loop: true,
    nav: true,
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<div id="BG" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="bg-item1">
    <div class="container row h-100">
      <div class="col-sm-12 align-self-center">
        <div class="bg-txt animated fadeInRight delay-2s">
          <span style="text-transform: uppercase; font-weight:bold;"> SOME TEXT </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-item2">
    <div class="container row h-100">
      <div class="col-sm-12 align-self-center">
        <div class="bg-txt animated fadeInRight delay-2s">
          <span style="text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold;"> SOME TEXT </span> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you need to animate individual items in your slide upon changing of the slides you could utilize the **`translate.owl.carousel`** event (**NOT** **`change.owl.carousel`** since it appears to not work properly for this purpose). See the following snippet for an example of that:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
  owl.owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    loop: true,
    nav: true,
  });

  $('.owl-carousel').on('translate.owl.carousel', function(e) {
    var index = e.item.index;
    $('.bg-txt').removeClass('animated fadeInRight delay-2s');
    $('.bg-txt').eq(index).addClass('animated fadeInRight delay-2s');
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<div id="BG" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="bg-item1">
    <div class="container row h-100">
      <div class="col-sm-12 align-self-center">
        <div class="bg-txt animated fadeInRight delay-2s">
          <span style="text-transform: uppercase; font-weight:bold;"> SOME TEXT </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-item2">
    <div class="container row h-100">
      <div class="col-sm-12 align-self-center">
        <div class="bg-txt">
          <span style="text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold;"> SOME TEXT </span> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes that's it. When use event change.owl.carousel it doesn't work correct. Now with translate.owl.carousel all is perfect. Thanks!